# How to support PDF viewing for all mobile browser?

Tags: android, ios, pdf, mobile, browser

I am using

```
<object>
```

to embed a pdf file on my website. e.g.

```
<object data="abc.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="abc.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

It works on all desktop browser, but on my android device, it does not show anything. Besides using the google pdf viewer (since it down-grade dramatically the pdf quality), are there any way to support all ios / android device browser? Or, what is the best way to handle this situation? Since there are lots of browser , How can I redirect them to the browser's pdf plugin download page , or should I just tell them to get one ? (Less user friendly). Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is just too just add a link to the `abc.pdf` it will open on a new tab.
This would work best for mobile browser rather than embeding or implementing plugins.

```
<a href="abc.pdf" target="_blank">ABC PDF file</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . As I am implement an ebook like web application . E.g. When user click on image, it show pdf on a top layer, is it possible on mobile device? thanks

Comment: yes it is possible, try it then if your have any problem, add more code to your post, or post a new question with the specific issue

Comment: That means I need the mobile browser with pdf viewer plugin installed?

Answer (score -1):

One cross-platform solution I've found is [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/).

Android-compatible embedding can be accomplished using an iFrame by providing both the URL to the ViewerJS project folder and the URL to the PDF to be embedded (relative to ViewerJS), separated by a hash:

```
<iframe src='../ViewerJS/#../../pdfs/pdf.pdf'></iframe>
```

Comment: This works but rendered PDF quality is not as good as it should be in it ...

Answer (score -2):

Better to use Google's Gview. I was having the same problem in my project: PDF was opening separately in mobile browsers, whereas it was opening perfectly in web, so I changed it to use Google Doc Gview. Example is given below:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?
    url=d11xs62myk100c.cloudfront.net/Conference/262/Misc/marcos-ascensin-spanish-national-research-council-csic-spain.ppt&amp;embedded=true'}"
    frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1000">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can check the compability of your mobile then download and save as .dox