# Link not clickable for mobile

Tags: html, css, drupal, href

I have some links that when clicked will show a PDF file.The link works when viewing from a laptop but when I try it on any mobile device (I tried iPhone6, galaxy s6 and huawei p9) the link does not do anything. I can click it, but thats about it.

[image]

```
<a href="http://localhost/mlndemo/sites/default/files/2017-02/voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief_0.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=420819" title="voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief.pdf">Bekijk hier de volledige vacature</a>
```

If anyone could help me with why this is not working on mobile devices that would be great :) Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:
Found this code on the drupal site which makes the target_blank. This seems to work as it now opens the file in a new window. I'll post the code here just for the sake that someone might need it. **This only works for Drupal (8)** Change THEME to your themename.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
*/
function THEME_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
  // Add target _blank attribute to all file links.
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $url = file_create_url($file->uri->value);
  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($variables['description'])) {
    $link_text = $file->filename->value;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $variables['description']->__toString();
  }
  $link = '<a href="'.$url.'" type="'.$file->filemime->value . '" length="' . $file->filesize->value . '" title="' . \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::escape($file->filename->value) . '" target="_blank">' . \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::escape($link_text) . '</a>';
  $variables['link']->setGeneratedLink($link);
}
```

Comment: There is likely no built in support for PDF

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564774/how-to-support-pdf-viewing-for-all-mobile-browser

Comment: Thanks, will check that out!

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably best try this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/mlndemo/sites/default/files/2017-02/voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief_0.pdf" title="voorbeeld_sollicitatiebrief.pdf" download>Bekijk hier de volledige vacature</a>
```

That should work.  It will download it, rather than direct to it.  Hopefully it works for you.  I haven't tested it.