# How to embed an inline PDF file in a web page that will be viewable on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications

I'm looking for how to embed a PDF file in a web page that will be viewable in the native Android browser / Chrome. If I use something like this:

```
<object data={'LINK_TO_PDF.pdf'+'#zoom=100&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0'}
type='application/pdf' 
width='100%' 
height='90%'>
<p>This browser does not support inline PDFs. Please download the PDF to view.</p>
</object>
```

It works great on Chrome, FireFox, and Edge on Windows. It works great in Safari on iPad (iPadOS) and Safari on iPhone (iOS).

**But it does not display on Android.**

The files are not publicly accessible, so I cannot use the Google Docs viewer.

PDF.js doesn't seem to help. PDFObject doesn't seem to help. I've looked a bit at ViewerJS.org, but most of its source code has not been updated in 7yrs.

I've seen lots of questions and answers about this, but most of them are old. Surely in 2021, there's a way to do this that works with Android?

(Having to download the file, open it up in a third-party PDF Viewer app, and then close it, switch apps, delete the PDF, and go back to the webpage seems very backwards.)

**How can this be done to provide a good user experience on Android?**

Comment: "viewable in the native Android browser" -- there is no single "native Android browser". "PDF.js doesn't seem to help" -- you might consider a [mcve] showing what you tried and explaining in detail what your results and problems were. Firefox on Windows probably uses PDF.js.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564774/how-to-support-pdf-viewing-for-all-mobile-browser

Comment: @Steve, no it's not a duplicate; similar, but this is more specific. The accepted answer there is not embedded.

Comment: @CommonsWare - any standard installed Android browser, or even that is readily available from the Google Play Store (e.g. runs on a current model mainstream tablet made by Samsung, etc..)  PDF.js is used by FireFox and works great on Windows, but when I test the PDF.js demo on a tablet, it doesn't work: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: @KJ - the specific need is: 1 tap to open a modal displaying the embedded PDF inline on the page, 1 tap to close that modal and return to the main view. I have this working 100% on Windows, but have not yet found a good solution on Android. This is needed for a warehouse environment where users have Android tablets and speed and simplicity is essential.

Comment: "when I test the PDF.js demo on a tablet, it doesn't work: mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html" -- that page, and its PDF document, load just fine on a Pixel 5 running Android 12 using Chrome. What tablet and browser did you use?

Comment: @KJ - Yeah, the problem is the Android browsers I've tried won't display a PDF like browsers on Windows - they need additional software to do so.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Perhaps I need to do some additional testing with PDF.js; it doesn't work on an Amazon Fire tablet with their Silk browser (not what is being used in the warehouse, but the only "Android-based" device I had handy for testing at the moment) - that tablet also didn't work with the object embed, but does work with ViewJS. (which I hesitate to use however because it isn't being maintained)